# Why wouldn't my Worksheet_Activate fire?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a workbook template for a client that needs to run code as soon as the workbook is opened. The problem is that my Worksheet_Activat event handlers aren't being run.

Code from ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Hello World!"
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets("Product").Activate
    Sheets("Raw Data").Activate
End Sub
```

This code gets run fine, and the MsgBox appears as soon as I create an instance of the template.

Code from the worksheets (They're the same with different strings for the MsgBox):

```
Private Sub Workseet_Activate()
    MsgBox "RawData"
End Sub
```

The code will not run when the sheet is activated via code, nor will it run when I manually change worksheets. What would cause the event handler not to handle the event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a misspelling: `Workseet_Activate()` should be `Worksheet_Activate()`.

Comment: You've gotta be kidding me... Thanks

Comment: @Telestia I kid you not :)

Comment: Well I'll accept the answer as soon as the time limit will let me, sounds like I need to get my coffee anyways.